# Is it common/accepted to bring a dog in Tuscany (Italy)?

Tags: italy, culture, nature-and-wildlife, etiquette

I understand Italian people have a very different etiquette when it comes to dining etc. Would we be allowed to bring a small dog to most terraces/restaurants? This will be in small towns, not tourist areas.

We have a carrier bag for him if needed. So far all wineries told us no, so I’m a little nervous about dining anywhere.

We don’t feel comfortable leaving him alone at the airbnb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to https://export.gov, a U.S. government website that assists exporters:

> Italy, with a population of 60 million people, has a pet population of 60 million.

Dogs and their owners are a common sight in Tuscan towns. This summer I dined in one of Lucca's best restaurants where I observed a couple with their small dog being warmly welcomed by management and staff. Dining *al fresco* with a dog in tow should not be a problem. If you intend to dine inside, I would recommend to check with the restaurant when making the table reservation.

Answer (score 10):

We have a very different etiquette compared to where? (yes, I'm italian)

Anyway, I see a lot of people bringing their dogs to the restaurant, so I don't see any problem.

Especially if the dog is small, and even more if you have a carrier bag, you should be ok. There could be places where animals are not allowed at all, but the majority of restaurants will allow small dogs.

Comment: Compared to any other country, is what I meant. Italians seem to think good behaviour during dinner and eating out is important. I'm from The Netherlands and people will easily bring their 3 running/screaming children + dog and then make a big mess. I was told in Italy this is very 'not done'. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: unfortunately there are also italian people making a huge mess at restaurants with children running everywhere :) I see it very often, and honestly I hate it. But it's just my point of view.. to be fair, I prefer a small dog sitting next to me much more than screaming children

Comment: Absolutely agreed!